# How to replace null values when there are multiple line items in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, null, sql-server-2012

When I use the following Query:

```
SELECT 
    [OrderNumberComplete], [OrderDate], [OrderTotal], 
    [RollupItemCount], [RollupItemName], [RollupItemSKU], 
    [RollupItemCode], [RollupItemQuantity]
FROM 
    [Order]
WHERE 
    OrderDate BETWEEN '10/01/2014' AND '10/31/2014'
ORDER BY 
    [RollupItemSKU]
```

I get the following results for orders with multiple line items.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohqMf.png
[image]

I need to be able to get this information to put it into a spread sheet.

I have a limited amount of query knowledge but I am willing to learn so anything anyone can suggest will go a long way.

Thanks in advanced for any help anyone can provide!

Comment: Are you just looking for `coalesce`?

Comment: What's wrong with the NULL text in your spreadsheet? What else would you put there to indicate an absence of any value?

Comment: do you want to replace those null values with zeros

Comment: I don't want to replace the null value, I want to see the data that is actually there. I know the data is there. The problem is that there are multiple line items for each of those orders and for some reason it defaults to NULL when there are multiple line items.

Comment: @Penlo, are you missing a join in your question? Your SQL query is just getting data from orders table, how come there is data for this columns and it it coming as Null

Answer (score 0):

Since you added "sql-server-2012" tag to your question I will assume you are using SQL Server. In that case in SQL Server Management Studio right click the database. Go with `Tasks -> Export Data`. Select Excel or CSV as destination. Then select "Use SQL" option to extract data

Comment: I tried this but the values were blank. 

I can see the data in the program I use for invoicing and it only has a null value for orders with Multiple line items.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ORDER BY 
    [RollupItemSKU] desc
```